# Convert string back to java Date

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I have one date string in the form of:

> "Sun Sep 18 00:05:35 GMT+07:00 2016"

I am getting this format from Media store Date Taken. How to convert it to Date object in java/android?

Comment: You have to use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Comment: Did it work buddy?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been asked hundreds of times already.

Answer (score 3):

The date in String can be parsed into the existing date object using `SimpleDateFormat` class. By creating `SimpleDateFormat` object and specifying the date pattern in its constructor you will be able to parse your date stored in string.

For you particular case code will look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

Date date = null;
try {
    date = format.parse(dateAsString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As it can be seen from the pattern:

> **EEE** - Day of the week in three letters (e.g. Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat)
>
> **MMM** - month of the year (between 0 and 11)
>
> **dd** - day of the month
>
> **HH** - hour (between 00 and 23)
>
> **mm** - minutes (between 00 and 59)
>
> **ss** - seconds (between 00 and 59)
>
> **z** - TimeZone (in your case, General Time Zone - GMT)
>
> **yyyy** - year

In addition, if you further want to pass this `Date` object to some `Calendar` object you will need to set time zone there too.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+07:00"));
calendar.setTime(date);
```

However, if you have your TimeZone changing then you can extract the timeZone part from the string:

```
String timeZone = dateAsString.substring(19, 28);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
calendar.setTime(date);
```

Just be careful with the starting and ending indexes of `substring()` function

Comment: what will be format string for GMT+07:00

Comment: @PraveenPandey I have updated my answer. Take a look at it and let me know if it worked